# Change FAB position when anchor is gone

Tags: android, position, android-coordinatorlayout, floating-action-button

im using a coordinatorLayout and a floating action button between two layers, like this:
[image: floating action button]

in the orange part i put a NestedScrollView to show alot of information about the product that have his photo on purple part.
When the users scrolls the layout and the anchor of the FAB ( the image on purple layout) is gone, the FAB keeps on top|right of the layout.
what im trying to do is: when the anchor is gone, the FAB go to buttom|right of the layout insted to remain on top of screen.
can you help me? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code to change the actionbar title when to toolbar collapses. You can reuse it to change the fab position instead of changing the title :

```
    ((AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar)).addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, State state) {
            switch (state) {
                case COLLAPSED:
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mMatch.getUniversity().getDisplayName());
                    break;
                case NOT_COLLAPSED:
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i cant use that because im not using the appbarlayout. i was, but the viewpager that contains the images had to be inside it, and with this the scrolling of the layout wasnt good :\ - thx for helping :)

Comment: Then I guess you can create a listener for the height value of your purple container, and when it is at the desired height then animate your FAB

Comment: that's exactly what i don't know how to do. :\

Comment: Well, without showing us your xml, I don't know which container you use, how your layout is built and in consequence help you a bit more. (you did say the orange part is a NestedScrollView but did not tell that much about the purple container)